# can we create IAP non consumable product id dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

i know how to create and use product IDs for a single non-consumable IAP.

I have searched for more than 2 days but can't find the answer.

my app has about 1000s list of books. when users click on a book cell(table view cell), an IAP calls and the user can pay for each.

is it possible to create product id dynamically in code at run time?
if not what is an alternative way to do to create a product id for each book cell?
Note: I don't want to use a credit system, because I want to sell each book individually.

Thank you

Comment: I had a product with two consumables and wanted to experiment with variants. Instead of adding AB testing to app and sending to appstore we used revenueCat. In revenuecat we can change associated product ID in real time. Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't. think so because IAP have to be consumed but your could have your "iap.id + isbn". You would have to keep track of what book the user purchases yourself.